# Не биндится свойство класса.WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, gui

```
<Window.Resources>
    <l:test x:Key="ThisTest" x:Name="MyTest"/>
</Window.Resources>

<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=MyTest, Path=k, Mode=TwoWay}"   Name="label1" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=MyTest, Path=k, Mode=TwoWay}"Name="label2"  />
```

Ожидал от кода, что когда я пишу текст в одном текстбокс, то он будет поялятьс я  другом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не, так не пойдёт, `ElementName` не ищет в ресурсах.

Делайте, например, так:

```
<TextBox х:Name="label1"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=label1, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="label2"/>
```